# Javascript object member function referred to globally not recognized in callback

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm having a problem with the following Javascript code (Phonegap in Eclipse):

```
function FileStore(onsuccess, onfail){
    //chain of Phonegap File API handlers to get certain directories

    function onGetSupportDirectorySuccess(dir){
        //stuff
        onsuccess();
    }

    function getDirectory(dir){
        return "something" + dir; 
    }
}

var onFileStoreOpened = function(){
    if (window.file_store instanceof FileStore){
      console.log('window.file_store is a FileStore');
      console.log(window.file_store.getDirectory('something'));
    }
}

var onDeviceReady = function(){
  window.file_store = new FileStore(onFileStoreOpened, onFileStoreFailure);  
}
```

Here, I want to do some things to initialize file services for the app, and then use them in my initialization from the callback. I get the following error messages in LogCat:

```
07-03 06:26:54.942: D/CordovaLog(223): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 40 : window.file_store is a FileStore
07-03 06:26:55.053: D/CordovaLog(223): file:///android_asset/www/cordova-1.8.1.js: Line 254 : Error in success callback: File7 = TypeError: Result of expression 'window.file_store.getDirectory' [undefined] is not a function.
```

After moving the code around and stripping out everything in getDirectory() to make sure it was valid, I'm not even sure I understand the error message, which suggested to me that getDirectory() is not seen as a member function of window.file_store, even though  window.file_store is recognized as a FileStore object. That makes no sense to me, so I guess that interpretation is incorrect. Any enlightenment will be greatly appreciated.

I've since tried the following:

```
window.file_store = {
    app_data_dir : null,
    Init: function(onsuccess, onfail){
        //chain of Phonegap File API handlers to get directories
        function onGetSupportDirectorySuccess(dir){
            window.file_store.app_data_dir = dir;
            console.log("opened dir " + dir.name);
            onsuccess();
        }
    },

    GetDirectory : function(){
        return window.file_store.app_data_dir; //simplified
    }
}


var onFileStoreOpened = function(){
    var docs = window.file_store.getDirectory();
    console.log('APPDATA: ' + docs.fullPath);
}

var onDeviceReady = function() {
    window.file_store.Init(onFileStoreOpened, onFileStoreFailure);  
}
```

and I get

```
D/CordovaLog(224): file:///android_asset/www/base/device.js: Line 81 : opened dir AppData
D/CordovaLog(224): file:///android_asset/www/cordova-1.8.1.js: Line 254 : Error in success callback: File7 = TypeError: Result of expression 'docs' [null] is not an object.
```

All I want to do here is make sure certain directories exist (I've removed all but one) when I start, save the directory object for future use, and then retrieve and use it after all initialization is done, and I don't want everything in the global namespace. Of course I would like to be able to use specific instances when necessary, and I'm disturbed that I can't make it work that way since it demonstrates there is a problem with my understanding, but I can't even get this to work with a single, global one. Is this a Javascript problem or a Phonegap problem?

Comment: I'm not really sure if I changed the underlying question with my edit with my second attempt at an approach, since I'm finally getting a different error, but it seems to me that the underlying question is about how to use the JS object model to do initialization, do a callback when initialization is finished, and then access the work that was done. I wish I could change the title to make this more clear.

Comment: and in particular, how to do _asynchronous_ initialization.

Comment: the `var docs = window.file_store.getDirectory();` should have `GetDirectory`, ie a capital G. I am gonna assume that was a typo while editing the question.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, your getDirectory function is a private function within FileStore. If you wanted to make it a 'member' or 'property' of FileStore, you would need to alter it a little within FileStore to make it like this:

```
 this.getDirectory = function(dir){ };
```

or leave it how it is and then set a property....

```
this.getDirectory = getDirectory();
```

this way when new FileStore is called it will have getDirectory as a property because the 'this' keyword is always returned when calling a function with 'new'

Hope this quick answer helps.  There's lots of stuff on the goog about constructor functions.

Comment: I tried both of these variants and it made no difference. I get exactly the same error. I made sure I cleaned the project, too, just to make sure. This is my first large-scale JS project, and clearly I have a lot to learn to get my head around the object model. Thanks anyway!

Comment: This post did remind me that there's work involved around the public/private issue. I forgot that all of these functions weren't public. I just tried moving the function out of the constructor and prefixing it with FileStore.prototype.getDirectory = function(dir), but then the "new FileStore()" failed completely.

Answer (score 1):

You understand it correctly. The getDirectory as it stands is a private function and cannot be called using the file_store instance.

Try this in the browser.

```
function FileStore(onsuccess, onfail){
   function onGetSupportDirectorySuccess(dir){
        //stuff
        onsuccess();
   }

   this.getDirectory = function (dir){
   return "something" + dir; 
   }
}

window.file_store = new FileStore('', '');  //the empty strings are just placeholders.
if (window.file_store instanceof FileStore){
    console.log('window.file_store is a FileStore');
    console.log(window.file_store.getDirectory('something'));
}
```

This will prove that the basic js code is working fine. If there still is a problem while using it in PhoneGap, comment.

Comment: Yes, this works, but if you then move the if statement into a new function "onSuccess" and pass it to the constructor, and in the constructor call onGetSupportDirectorySuccess(), window.file_store is no longer an instanceof FileStore when onSuccess is called. This desktop Chrome behavior actually makes more sense to me (coming mostly from C++) than file_store being an instanceof FileStore but not really in the Android case.

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.9.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File has an example of how each step is done async. The next step is passed as a callback to the prev step. Your logging statements claim that app_data_dir has some value, but the next logging statement says its null. ... Could you maybe post the entire (simplified bare essential) code as a gist or something? Without seeing who is calling what, its difficult to diagnose this.